# How to create Expandablelistview using retrofit 2 library?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to fetch Expandable list view using retrofit 2.x library from web service but header is set but child list view is not set. what is the problem.
Here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    //Creating an object of our api interface
    ListAPI api = retrofit.create(ListAPI.class);

    Call<List<ExpHeadItem>> call = api.getItems();
    //Defining the method
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ExpHeadItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ExpHeadItem>> call, Response<List<ExpHeadItem>> response) {
            //Dismissing the loading progressbar
            loading.dismiss();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                headList.addAll(response.body());
                ExpandableListAdapter rt_adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this ,headList);
                expList.setAdapter(rt_adapter);
            }
            else {
                int statusCode = response.code();

                ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
            }

        }
```

and i am using two class for header and child view.
**ExpHeadItem.java**

```
@SerializedName("name")
String Name;

List<ExpChildItem> Items = new ArrayList<ExpChildItem>();

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public List<ExpChildItem> getItems() {
    return Items;
}
```

and
**ExpChildItem.java**

```
@SerializedName("title")
private String Name;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
```